# Hide UIView inside TableView and update constraints

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uitableview

I have custom tableview cell that has UITextView and UIView under it. TextView is using sizeToFit method to adjust it's height to content. View has fixed height. Cell height is changing to fit the content.  Cells are shown fine.

What I want is to hide View in some of my cells. Bu not only set its hidden property to be true but also to adjust cell's height.

[image]

Comment: your question is not at all clear, please post screenshots along with code.

Comment: @DarkInnocence, I added one screenshot - is it clear with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you view has a fixed height? So, if it has the height constraint add IBOutlet to it.

and when you want to hide your view just set it constant to zero.

```
heightConstraint.constant = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

To make your life easier (if you're using iOS 9 and above), use a `UIStackView` in your custom cell.

Now, the following steps are for making your `UITableViewCell` auto-adjust its height for `UITextView`

1. Add this settings inside the `viewDidLoad()` method of your controller and modify as needed for your `UITableView`.

   ```
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   ```
2. Implement the `UITextViewDelegate` and make sure you're setting your textView's delegate to self.

   ```
   // MARK: - TextView Delegate

   extension YourController: UITextViewDelegate {

       func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
           let currentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
           UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
           self.tableView.beginUpdates()
           self.tableView.endUpdates()
           UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
           tableView.setContentOffset(currentOffset, animated: false)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Lastly, turn off the horizontal and vertical scroll indicator of your textView.

Then, for toggling the visibility of your any views in your cell, just toggle it and reload your tableView.